# Can abandoned patents or applications be refiled or sold?

Tags: ep2196243b1

In reference to the patent: [EP2196243B1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2196243B1)

Since the inventor failed to complete the patent, is it considered public knowledge and therefor not patentable?

Can anyone sell this abandoned product?

Comment: Duplicate of [Is an expired patent in the public domain?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/5766/11895)